# Expression Tree for a Collection

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I can do the following manually but need to build it up using System.Linq.Expressions.

```
.Where(x => x.OrganizationPersonRoles.Any(o => o.OrganizationId == value))
```

I can get it built up to the .Any and know I need to do an Expression.Call for the Any method but don't know how to build up the inner lambda (o => o.OrganizationId == value).

```
Expression exp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
Type type = typeof(T);
PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("OrganizationPersonRoles");
exp = Expression.Property(exp, pi);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(exp, arg);
```

Edit:
It's the ".Any" part I can't figure out how to build the expression. "OrganizationPersonRoles" is a collection on "Person".  Something like:

```
var anyMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.Name == "Any")
    .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

var body = Expression.Call(exp, anyMethod, "Expression For Inner Lambda");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, arg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the lambda `o => o.OrganizationId == value` as follows.

```
int value = 5;
var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var oParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Organization), "o");

var expression =
    Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Any", new[] { typeof(Organization) },
            Expression.Property(xParameter, "OrganizationPersonRoles"),
            Expression.Constant(
                Expression.Lambda(
                    Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.Property(oParameter, "OrganizationId"),
                        Expression.Constant(value, typeof(int))),
                    oParameter),
                typeof(Expression<Func<Organization, bool>>))),
        xParameter);
```

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to use `Expression.Variable` here. How is the value of that variable going to be set?

Comment: @svick Yeah I just used that because, in the question, nothing mentions where the `value` variable is coming from. `Expression.Constant(/*the actual value of "value"*/, typeof(int))` is probably better, assuming the `value` variable has type `int`. I'll change it.

Comment: It's the "Any" part I can't get the expression tree for.  `x => x.OrganizationPersonRoles.Any(...`

Comment: @TimothyShields That seems close but it's giving me a "Argument types do not match" error.  I'm going to tweak it a bit and see if I can't pound it into shape.

Comment: @NicholasSnyder It's probably that `typeof(T)` should be `typeof(Organization)`. I just changed that.

Comment: @TimothyShields The "Argument types do not match" error" was because my `value` was a string but should be an int.  It is now giving me the following error: "No generic method 'Any' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic."

Comment: @NicholasSnyder See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534338(v=vs.100).aspx When a method needs an argument of type `T`, if you want to call the method with `Expression.Call` you need to pass an `Expression<T>` for the argument. I think the second argument to `Any` needs to be wrapped with `Expression.Constant`. I'm changing that now.

Comment: @TimothyShields What is the last part, `typeof(Expression<Func<Organization, bool>>))` for? It doesn't like this and gives "Argument 6: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'".  I took that part off and it compiles but still gives the "No generic method 'Any'" error.

Comment: @NicholasSnyder I had the parentheses wrong. That should have been the second argument to `Expression.Constant`, not the sixth argument of `Expression.Call`. Browser code... Please try the latest code, I fixed the parentheses.

Comment: @TimothyShields Still getting the "No generic method 'Any'" error